# Why don't the list and code buttons appear in my editor?

Tags: angular, plugins, tinymce

I've followed [the docs](https://www.ephox.com/blog/angular-2-and-tinymce/) to set up a TinyMCE component in my Angular project. Got the editors showing up but am running into two snags (so far):

I can't seem to get list formatting buttons to appear. I've tried using advlist by importing `tinymce/plugins/advlist` and adding them to `plugins: ['link', 'table', 'advlist']`, but I'm not seeing any change to the editor.

I'm also trying to find where to turn on the code editing button.

Using TinyMCE 4.5.6, angular-cli1.0.0-rc.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading the plugins for lists is the first part of getting them working.  You also need to add them to the `toolbar` configuration option:

```
toolbar: [
  "bold italic | bullist numlist",
  "code"
],
```

To use the code view you need to both load the `code` plugin in your plugin list and add the `code` toolbar button to the `toolbar` configuration option.

**Note**:  The `advlist` plugin expects that the `lists` plugin is also loaded so in order for `advlist` to work you likely need to also add the `lists` plugin.

Comment: Thanks for that. Not sure why I didn't stumble on that tidbit in my searching. Only problem is bullish and numlist still aren't showing up. Is there another dependency I'm missing, like the images or something?

Comment: Did you load the `list` plugin?  I see `advlist` in your code but not `list`.  The `advlist` plugin relies on the `list` plugin.

Comment: I had tried that but got errors until I took a closer look at the plugins directory. The version I have is called "lists". Once I made that change, it all came up. Thanks a lot for the help, this was getting frustrating!

Comment: Indeed its called `lists` - I edit my answer with a note on that.