# TinyMCE "List" and "Advlist" plugins are Not Showing

Tags: angular, tinymce

So I have the plugins enabled and the toolbar edited so it would show numlist and bullist however neither are showing. the other plugins are showing just fine, it's just these two that aren't showing in my editor. 
I've checked my tinymce assets folder and the two plugins are definitely there, so I'm at a loss as to why they're not displaying like the other plugins are.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is something I think needs emphasis and it was a little hidden in this stackoverflow question:
[Why don't the list and code buttons appear in my editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371180/why-dont-the-list-and-code-buttons-appear-in-my-editor)

The plugin is called "lists" (PLURAL) and the other plugin is "advlist" (SINGULAR). These have to be typed correctly or else the plugins won't be found (and advlist will not load without lists being enabled as well).